# Total on Measure with Max Date not reflecting correctly

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get the total amount from the latest transaction for all clients. See below for the sample table:

[image: Sample Data]

When creating a table in PowerBI, I get the following where the total only reflects the last 2 latest transaction (75) instead of the total of the entire records (235):

[image: Power BI Table]

Here's my measure (Sheet1 is the table name):

_Latest amount =
VAR _maxd = maxx(Sheet1, Sheet1[Date].[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE
(SUMX(Sheet1, Sheet1[Amount]), Sheet1[Date] = _maxd)

Can someone help and take a look into this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect the aggregation for the grand total to default to sum? It doesn't; rather, the aggregation(s) you specify within your measure are applied equally at the grand total level. In your case, this means taking the sum of Amount for all Clients for the latest Date, i.e. the two entries from 03/17.

To override that aggregation, you'd need something like:

```
=
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Sheet1,
        Sheet1[Client],
        "Latest Amount",
            CALCULATE (
                SUM ( Sheet1[Amount] ),
                FILTER ( Sheet1, Sheet1[Date] = MAX ( Sheet1[Date] ) )
            )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        ISFILTERED ( Sheet1[Client] ),
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Sheet1[Amount] ),
            FILTER ( Sheet1, Sheet1[Date] = MAX ( Sheet1[Date] ) )
        ),
        SUMX ( T1, [Latest Amount] )
    )
```